# Can I use old fence boards for building raised garden vegetable beds?

Tags: wood, fence, backyard, pressure-treated, cedar

I'm in the process of replacing an old fence and I want to reuse the fence boards and posts to build some vegetable beds.

I've read online that the type of wood is important for veg beds, as older pressure treated pine used to contain copper and arsenic which may be absorbed into the soil.

I have no idea what type of wood the old fence was constructed from, all I know is that it is likely an original fence (house built in 1976).

How can I find out what type of wood it is?

Comment: Take a piece to a lumberyard, not a big box store.  They have people that are familiar with multiple species of wood.   If you really have a 47 year old piece of outside fence that isn't rotted, molded and split, you may consider saving it for a museum.